# Корректный подсчет элементов с определенным классом в фильтре

Tags: jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/o1fhvzpr/

Создал фильтр, но при выборе нескольких категорий в фильтре, а затем при отключении хотя бы одной получается, что количество элементов с классом `".filter--active"` увеличивается. Почему некорректно считает ? Вот код подсчета непосредственно:

```
  parent = $(this).closest('.filter').find(' li.filter--active');
   $(this).closest('.filter').find('.circle.list-col').html(parent.length+1);
```

Смотреть лучше на разрешении больше 1000 пикселей по ширине, на меньших разрешениях фильтр неактивен

Пробовал еще следующим образом, но считается тоже неправильно (правда я data-prefix одинаковый поставил для элементов одной категории)

```
el_class = $(this).closest('.filter').find('li a').data('prefix');
         active = $(this).closest('.filter').find('li.filter--active a[data-prefix=\"'+el_class+'\"]').length;
```

Comment: `$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().` - сейчас глаза взорвутся

Comment: Как можно было проще записать ?

Comment: `$(this).closest('.filter').`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Жаль что никто не смог помочь.В моем случае можно было так:

```
var count_li = $(this).parent().children('li.filter--active:not(:first-child)').length;
```